# Is there a way to access files or folders in the clipboard via nodejs?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am working on a little electron project to get started with that particular environment. Right now I am testing the clipboard and it seems like I can only read and write text, HTML, RTF and a [Native Image](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/native-image/) from / to the clipboard. But is there a way to read in files via `fs.readSync(path)` and then copy it to the clipboard to simply paste it somewhere on the desktop etc. ?

Note: I have already taken a look at a bunch of clipboard packages on npms.io but I didn't find one that has the desired capability.

Comment: Looking for the same thing, did you find anything ?

Comment: @trebor Sadly i didn't, it looks like you have to write a C++ extension yourself for that matter